# Splash Screen in Secondary Tile Navigation wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

Do we need to show splash screen while navigating from secondary tiles? Because the application is opening with new instance.
Note: In Windows phone Certification Requirements it stats that 'The app may provide a splash screen image in a file called SplashScreenImage.jpg in the root of the XAP package while the app is still trying to load'.

[Technical Requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certification requirements will not require you to manually display a splash image. The splash image, SplashScreenImage.jpg as you mentioned, is displayed automatically by the OS, and is not something you need to worry about handling manually.

Comment: Please suggest me that do we need to show splash screen image while loading application from first page or else by giving the image in application with SplashScreenImage.png is enough. ?
As per i know showing splash screen in seconary tiles not needed. [Splash Screen Display in Primary Tiles](http://windowsphonegeek.com/forums/windows-phone-development/splash-screen-in-secondary-tile-navigation-wp8)

Comment: The splash images are not something you add to your app code. The splash is simply the SplashScreenImage file in the root of your app